# Additional fundamental forces induced by (unknown or not) massless fermions?

Tags: fermions, interactions, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

Just thinking about one stupid question: what if there are some massless fermions we don't have detected by some reason and they have interactions (related or not with the weak force and the Fermi constant)? Is that possibility excluded for any known reason? After all, neutrinos could have a massless state yet, or not? Maybe neutrinos and the Higgs are portals to these new extra forces. What are the current theoretical and experimental limitations to this fermionic force idea?